# Validation. In the View? or Service Layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to figure out how to best do my validation for my mvc project. I come up with 2 ways but not sure which way is best(if any)

1. Basic validation in my mvc controller(or whatever consumes my service layers) and business logic in the service layers.

Once validation is done in the view the domain object would be passed and then checked for business logic and then saved to the db.

This means though that if I reuse my service layer every app will have to write validation for the same stuff(example "name" is required). If they forget to do this then the service layer will crash.

2. All validation done in the service layer.

This would give one point of valdiation and would always ensure that all data is correct before saving to the db.

This creates in my opinion lots of overhead though as how I see it. I will need a viewmodel, then take the viewmodel and transfer it to a data transfer object, let that go into the service layer and validate it.

If it is valid then map it to the domain object and save it.

Comment: I am voting to close this as opinion based as dozens of similar threads about validation were closed before.

Answer (score 1):

All validation should be implemented on the back end, since you have no control over what happens on an end user's browser. The most important goal of validation is protecting the integrity of your system.

Since any validation you perform in the view would be duplication, implement only that which enhances the user experience (e.g. responsive design, reducing calls to the server, etc.).

Comment: Sorry when I meant view. I should have said "controller" so back end but not service layer.

Answer (score 0):

Validation In View only is trouble maker.because based on java script that professional user inspecting and delete some javascript code.I validate my project in front-end and back-end both.